# How to find the limit of the following recursive sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $a_{n}=1$

$ a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac{1}{n} $ if $ a^{2}_n\le2 $

$ a_{n+1}=a_n-\dfrac{1}{n} $ if $ a^{2}_n\ge2 $

the limit of the mentioned sequence is $\sqrt{2}$ . I tried to show that $|a_n-\sqrt{2}|< \frac{2}{n}$ for every index $n$ as the claim of the book, but I can't.
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Straightforward induction should work.

Comment: induction doesn't work!

Comment: Base case is easy, and for the step you have two different cases. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Dear Geyer, I can't prove that it's true for (n+1)th, supposing it's true for nth term; especially, because it's like piecewise functions; I don't know (a_n)^2 is less than or greater than 2 for nth term; I tried both cases separately, but I failed! would you please provide some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: $|a_n - \sqrt{2}|<2/n$ for all $n$.

Proof by induction:

$n=1$: $|a_n-\sqrt{2}| = |1-\sqrt{2}|<1<2/1$.

$n \to n+1$: Assuming that $|a_n - \sqrt{n}| < 2/n$, there are two cases.

Case 1: $a_n^2 < 2$, i.e., $a_n < \sqrt{2}$. By induction hypothesis, $\sqrt{2}-2/n < a_n < \sqrt{2}$, so $a_{n+1} = a_n + 1/n$ satisfies $\sqrt{2}- 1/n < a_{n+1} < \sqrt{2}+1/n$, and $|a_n - \sqrt2| < 1/n \le 2/(n+1)$

Case 2: $a_n^2 > 2$, i.e., $a_n > \sqrt{2}$. By induction hypothesis, $\sqrt{2}< a_n < \sqrt{2}+2/n$, so $a_{n+1} = a_n - 1/n$ satisfies $\sqrt{2}- 1/n < a_{n+1} < \sqrt{2}+1/n$, and $|a_n - \sqrt2| < 1/n \le 2/(n+1)$

(The case $a_n = \sqrt{2}$ will never happen since $a_n$ is rational for all $n$. In the statement of the problem this case is ambiguous, but it does not really matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Note first that $a_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers, hence $a_n^2\not =2$ for all $n$.

We define two strictly increasing sequences of integers, $n_k$ and $m_k$ in the following manner. We have $a_{n_k}<\sqrt{2}$, and $a_{1+n_k}>\sqrt{2}$. We have $a_n>\sqrt{2}$ for $n=1+n_k,\cdots, m_k$. We have $a_{1+m_k}<\sqrt{2}$, and $a_n<\sqrt{2}$ for $n=1+m_k,\cdots,n_{k+1}$.(These sequences exists by the fact the the series $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent)

If $k$ is given, we see

A) that $a_n$ is decreasing on $[1+n_k, m_k]$, hence we have for $1+n_k \leq n\leq  m_k$ that  $a_{m_k}\leq a_n\leq a_{1+n_k}$, and the inequalities $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}\leq a_n\leq a_{n_k}+\frac{1}{n_k}\leq \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{n_k}$

B) that $a_n$ is increasing on $[1+m_k, n_{k+1}]$, hence we have  for $1+m_k\leq n\leq n_{k+1}$ that $\displaystyle a_{1+m_k}\leq a_n\leq a_{n_{k+1}}$, and the inequality $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{m_k} \leq a_{m_k}-\frac{1}{m_k}=a_{1+m_k}\leq a_n\leq \sqrt{2}$. As $m_k\geq n_k$, we get $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n_k} \leq a_n\leq \sqrt{2}$.

C)  Now for all $k$ and $n\in [1+n_k, n_{k+1}]$, we get $\displaystyle |a_n-\sqrt{2}|\leq \frac{1}{n_k}$, and it is easy to finish.